# Java - Regex - Replace multiple dots and commas with just one dot

Tags: java

Using TextField to place double/integer numbers, want to change any number with "," to number with "." and remove multiple dots and commas.

```
String test = "0....,,,,,,,....754568";
test.replaceAll(<?IDK?>, ".");
```

`<?IDK?>` means that I don't know what to put there.

Examples:
**4,5** → **4.5**
**6,,,,2** → **6.2**
**0....,,,,,,,....754568** → **0.754568**
**7...2** → **7.2**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to replace all `.` or `,` by `.` :

```
test.replaceAll("[.,]+", ".");
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly matches what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a regular expression, for example, to identify numbers which have more than one dot or comma you can use the following :

```
\d+[.,]{2,}+\d
```

You can adjust it based on your needs.

If you want to test it, this website is useful : https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html